# Extraer parte de una cadena entre dos puntos especificos

Tags: c#, string

Recientemente me vi en la necesidad de extraer todos los valores que se encuentran entre dos puntos especificados de una cadena, en este caso todo lo que se encuentre dentro de los paréntesis `"()"`.

**Cúal sería la forma mas optima o adecuada para hacer esto?**

```
string cadena = string.Empty, resultado = string.Empty;
```

Tengo un correo electrónico que el cual tiene un formato predefinido, en el cual solo cambian los valores que se encuentras entre `()`

Ejemplo `cadena`:

```
Hola, amigo X, ..........

bla bla bla bla
.......
('A','B','valorX','valorY',N...) //lo que quiero obtener.
.......
mas texto...
....

Se despide, atentamente, Pedro...
```

Buscando distintas formas de hacerlo lo solucione usando una de estas formas presentadas a continuación":

1- Utilizando [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
resultado = cadena.Split('(', ')')[1];
```

ó

```
resultado = cadena.Split("()".ToCharArray())[1];
```

---

2- Con Expresiones Regulares [Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
resultado = Regex.Match(cadena, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

---

3- Con [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) aplicando un poco de matemáticas:

```
int posInicial = cadena.LastIndexOf("(") + 1;
int longitud = cadena.IndexOf(")") - posInicial;

resultado = cadena.Substring(posInicial, longitud);
```

---

Con cada una de esas formas de hacerlo se obtiene el mismo resultado:

```
#resultado 'A','B','valorX','valorY',N...
```

A sinceridad me resulta complicado entender como funcionan las expresiones regulares, siempre las veo como un montón de código jeroglíficos indescifrables...

Entonces: **Cúal sería la forma mas optima o adecuada para hacer esto?**

Comment: Optima y adecuada genera que la pregunta sea basada en opiniones. Optima en que sentido? adecuada en que sentido? si funciono, una microoptimizacion es casi innecesaria.

Comment: Optimo en cuanto a consumo de recursos, aunque sea una _microoptimizacion_  considero que si en todo el sistema esas microoptimizaciones nunca se toman en cuenta, poco a poco la suma de todo eso se vuelve grande, no se si me doy a entender.

Comment: o sea memoria? optimo en memoria y no en velocidad?

Comment: @gbianchi en ambas, cual consume menos memoria, y cual lo haría mas rápido. Cual me recomiendas usar?

Comment: Nunca hice semejante analisis. el string que estas mostrando es despreciable en todos los casos.

Comment: @gbianchi Ese string solo es un ejemplo, pero bueno gracias.

Comment: Para el tema de  velocidad y uso de memoria, investiga el tema de benchmarks para tú mismo evaluar la efectividad de cada metodo y sacar tus conclusiones ..

Comment: Ademas de que en este caso, podrias probarlo tu mismo, pon entonces un ejemplo mas realista o algo que valga la pena. Si son todas cadenas de ese estilo, no tiene sentido. si vamos a hablar de cadenas con miles o millones de caracteres, bueno, es otra cosa...

Comment: viendo el ejemplo a simple vista sin poder hacer un test de rendimiento, el split solo esta haciendo una operacion, las demas estas usando 2 o mas funciones

Comment: @JackNavaRow por tal razón he usado `Split()` pero quería saber que piensan ustedes también, ademas debe haber mas formas de lograr esto ya sea con `Linq` u otras formas...

Comment: Esto seria mejor para el [chat], pero a simple vista, el peor seria la regex, seguido del split, y el mejor seria el indexof. pero sin benchmark ni nada, solo mirando que hace cada uno... Pero prueba cada uno y nos cuentas

Comment: Y un correo electronico sigue siendo despreciable.. fijate en la cantidad de caracteres.. y otra forma de medirlo, seria ver el IL generado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta con hacer un análisis de complejidad.

El algoritmo mas eficiente en cuanto a memoria y velocidad seria el cuarto. Básicamente tienes que fijarte en el tiempo lineal y consumo de memoria de cada algoritmo.

En el primer algoritmo:

```
cadena.Split('(', ')')[1];
```

Se itera la cadena en tiempo lineal, buscando la cantidad de caracteres dados en el arreglo del Split (pasados como parametros en el metodo) y por cada uno va a iterar la lista hasta `N`, donde `N` es la longitud de la cadena. Ahora bien, el necesitara correr la lista y creara `M` variables temporales por cada caracter en el `Split`, para luego crear una lista de valores por indexacion el cual su acceso es en tiempo constante `O(1)`.

Como resultado obtendras `O((N * M) + 1)` donde `N` es la longitud del `string` y `M` la cantidad de `substrings` generados en cada operacion de `Split`.

El segundo algoritmo:

```
cadena.Split("()".ToCharArray())[1];
```

Básicamente es el mismo procedimiento que el primer algoritmo, solo que aquí, consumirá mas memoria, porque tendrá que crear un array de caracteres y crear una variable temporal e iterar el `string` que en este caso viene siendo `"()"`.

El tercer algoritmo:

```
Regex.Match(cadena, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Es un arma de doble filo. La complejidad radicara en la longitud o complejidad de la regla, valga la redundancia. Esto solo se debe utilizar si la regla es un poco compleja, validar emails, direcciones, formatos de numeros, mentions y hashtags, etc... Por ejemplo, si no fueras a utilizar Regex para validar mentions o hashtags en una cadena, tendrías que crear un algoritmo gigantezco y Árbol de Intervalos para obtener los indices donde se encuentra cada mention o hashtag. Para trabajar con strings de cantidades masivas, gastarias muchisima memoria intentando obtener todos los substrings que son mentions o hashtags en cadenas gigantes. Las expresiones regulares se deben utilizar como validador de cadenas complejas, ya que te evitan crear un algoritmo gigantesco. Obviamente en este caso, es el que tiene mayor complejidad y consumo de memoria.

Para el cuarto algoritmo:

```
int posInicial = cadena.LastIndexOf("(") + 1;
int longitud = cadena.IndexOf(")") - posInicial;
resultado = cadena.Substring(posInicial, longitud);
```

Tendrias que iterar dos veces la longitud `N` de la cadena para luego obtener el resultado en `N` por lo que la complejidad seria `O((2 * N) + N)`.

Por lo que en un top seria:

1. `O((2 * N) + N)` el cuarto algoritmo.
2. `O((N * M) + 1)` el primer algoritmo.
3. `O((N * M) + 1)` el segundo algoritmo. consume mas memoria el primer algoritmo.
4. `O(?)` el cuarto algoritmo. Regex es el mas complicado y el que consume mas memoria. De antemano se puede saber que es el que tiene la mayor complejidad por el proceso que implica.

Ten en cuenta que en tu ejemplo estos tiempos son insignificantes (ninguno llega a `1ms` de procesamiento). Por lo que si quieres ver el resultado de una mejor forma, tendrias que probarlo con una longitud gigante para la cadena). Esta respuesta es basada en mi experiencia en la algoritmia, si alguien esta dispuesto a documentarse y contradecirme o encontrar algun error, estoy a disposición de discutirlo.

Puedes leer la documentacion para el analisis de Algoritmos [Understanding Big O Notation](https://www.coengoedegebure.com/understanding-big-o-notation/) o [Este link esta mas completo](https://www.cs.us.es/~jalonso/cursos/i1m/temas/tema-28.html).

Comment: Me parece una buena explicación, Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Primero y principal, calcular las complejidades sin ver el algortimo real, es algo que suena medio magico. Mas alla de eso, IndexOf para lo que tu llamas el cuarto caso, esta mal calculado, ya que podrias calcular la segunda posicion necesaria sin recorrer devuelta toda la cadena, ya que indexof puede recibir la posicion inicial, con lo cual no estarias recorriendo dos veces la cadena. Solo una.. desde dos puntos distintos, y sin necesidad de recorrerla toda como en los otros casos. y en cuanto al consumo de memoria, tenes algun ejemplo real de cual consume mas?

Comment: @gbianchi me base en la complejidad de cada algoritmo que investigue.  Si buscas encontraras los algoritmos expuestos. Sobre lo de `indexOf` me estoy basando en su ejemplo, ya se que se puede iniciar desde un indice que indiques, pero analice solo los algoritmos que el publico en su respuesta.

Comment: Puedes encontrarlos [aqui](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) en el buscador.